# Young adult sci-fi / chaos theory from 90s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Trying to find a young adult book from the 80s or 90s, it may have actually been part of a series. Seem to remember it involved chaos theory and, towards the end of one book, the protagonist encounters himself from another dimension (?) Can't remember much more except possibly a love interest that both the protagonist and his other self pursued (?) Thank you!

Comment: Any more you might remember could be helpful.

Comment: Could it have been about 6 young adults, 2 each of 3 races, that travel in a space ship to earth and discover a plot to breed pure races?

Comment: Not necessarily any better fit than the first one, but I'm wondering if it could be the [Apprentice Adept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept) series. Book 4 has a pair that can switch frames and each falls in love with someone in the "wrong" frame.

Comment: Tossing out a few possibilities here: could be something by William Sleator (maybe 'Strange Attractors'), possibly 'Parallelities' by Alan Dean Foster, or even Michael Lawrence's 'A Crack in the Line' or its sequels. Can't rule out a couple of adult books: 'The Man Who Folded Himself' by David Gerrold and 'The Man Who Turned Into Himself' by David Ambrose.

Comment: I need to know as well! Its decent from the 90’s, a crack in the line is from 2004.
There was a book that I’m sure had to do with the fourth dimension, and I was sure it was called 4 squared, but no young adult novel with that title and plot exists that I can find.

Comment: This sounds like a book I read around that time also, and I remember it as being named "Chaos Theory", but can't find it under that name. It's possible that is a bad memory based on it being repeated in the contents, or it was a large-print subtitle on the cover, but I remember this taking place on earth (entirely, or almost so), and the device they used to time/space travel was a wristband with a patch of something textured like velcro you brushed against to activate, and there was concern about warping into a mountain or space because of earth's rotation. Hope this helps either of us.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like *0X* (1975), the final book from Piers Anthony's ["Of Men and Manta"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_Man_and_Manta) series.  I read it when I was quite young (early 80s), but exactly the same plot elements have stuck with me: the references to chaos theory --here revolving around a sentient cellular automaton --and the alternate universe antagonist versions of the main characters.  The Wikipedia entry doesn't have much about those portions of the book, but there is more detail confirming my memories [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=wcomJEpp08oC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=piers+anthony+parallel+universes&source=bl&ots=coMBMD0A3l&sig=m_6T7v0TOb6yDp7td8QE16F3awo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjExaefx5nZAhVIeKwKHbAjCecQ6AEIWjAJ#v=onepage&q=piers%20anthony%20parallel%20universes&f=false).  One of the details that stuck out to me is that some of the characters that met their alternate selves ended up diverging greatly from them just from the experience of having met them.

Anthony would go on to revisit parallel universes and chaos theory (a bit incoherently) in his [Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_series) series.